# release обьектов в Obj-C без ARC

Tags: objective-c, утечка-памяти

Начал изучать обжси уже с ARC,теперь наверстываю знания. Вопрос следующий: что произойдет если отправить release unretain-обьекту два раза?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Краш будет рано или поздно т.к. объекта в памяти уже не будет.

Answer (score 0):

При использовании ARC не допускаются сообщения: release, retain, dealloc